# UICollectionview immediate layout update

Tags: ios, swift, layout, ios7, uicollectionview

I am having a small problem I just can't find a solution for.

I am trying to invalidate the layout of a UICollectionViewFlowLayout after the first cell is dequeued in `collectionView(collectionView:, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:)` so it fits it's content before appearing to the user. I need to do this this way, because I need to access the cells ui elements, which are not available the first time `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is called.

In iOS 8 this works fine, but in iOS 7 `invalidateLayout` doesn't update the layout immediately, just as stated in the Apple Documentation:

> It is useful to remember that calling the invalidateLayout method does not begin the layout update process immediately. The method merely marks the layout as being inconsistent with the data and in need of being updated. During the next view update cycle, the collection view checks to see whether its layout is dirty and updates it if it is. In fact, you can call the invalidateLayout method multiple times in quick succession without triggering an immediate layout update each time.

Now I am wondering if there is a workaround for iOS 7 which updates the flow layout immediately.

`reloadData` is not a solution, because calling it while dequeuing cells messes up the whole collectionview.

Comment: Uh, so you want dynamically sized height collectionViewCells ?

Comment: Yes, it already works fine on iOS8. First time cellForIndexPath is called i store the default cell so i can access the font i setup in the storyboard. Then i invalidate the layout

Comment: If you're not using attributed HTML parsed text and you have a basic cell with one blob of text, you can calculate the height required to render the text of the UILabel, by calling something like `[@"my blob of string" boundRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) .... ];`  This works for iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: I am actually using this method, using the font of the label in the cell as an attribute. My problem is that invalidateLayout isn't called immediately in iOS 7 but it is in iOS 8. I already found an solution myself i will post in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an solution for `invalidateLayout` not triggering immediately: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called after the collectionview has been loaded, so I am calling the invalidate method in this method. It still is interesting that this actually works.